# What is the underlying architecture of Spacy's blank model. [spacy.blank("en")]

Tags: python, spacy

Either I missed out on their documentation, or they have made it really hard to find. Any pointers to where I can find information regarding the underlying model would be helpful

For more context, I am using it for an NER task with custom labels, but I don't think that should matter very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blank model does not have pre-trained tagger, parser and NER.

`spacy.blank` function is here: [Github link](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/320a8b14814c7e0c6dce705ad7bf0f13bf64b61c/spacy/__init__.py#L33). It just calls `util.get_lang_class(name)` which essentially loads a language-specific module from here: [Github link to spacy/lang](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/)

Here's the link to the code for the blank English model:
[Github link to spacy English model](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/)

The detailed documentation is here: [Adding new languages](https://spacy.io/usage/adding-languages#language-data)

If the only thing you are changing is NER, I would start with the pre-trained model (I assume English), and just disable NER pipe:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable = ['ner'])
```

Using this model instance `nlp`, you would train your NER (if it is ML-based) or add EntityRuler pipe (if your NER is rule-based). This way you will still have POS-tagger and dependency parser available to you. After you finished with training, just save the model using `to_disk`. If you use EntityRuler (rule-based NER), you will need to write a few lines of code to register the new pipe (well-documented on their web-ste)